# Ruby - rock paper scissor game using While, if/else statements, player vs computer

Tags: ruby

```
$player_count = 0
$computer_count = 0

what_to_include = %w{r p s}

paper = "p"
rock = "r"
scissors = "s"

def computer_input
  computer = rand(3)
  if computer == 0
    computer = "p"
  elsif computer == 1
    computer = "r"
  else
    computer = "s"
  end
end


while true

puts "Player Score: #{$player_count}, \tComputer Score: #{$computer_count}"

print "Choose rock (r), paper (p), or scissors (s): "
player_input = gets.chomp.downcase

  if player_input == rock && computer_input == scissors
    puts "Player chose rock. \nComputer chose scissors."
    puts "Rock beats scissors, player wins the round."
    $player_count += 1

  elsif player_input == scissors && computer_input == paper
    puts "Player chose scissors. \nComputer chose paper."
    puts "Scissors beat paper, player wins the round."
    $player_count += 1

  elsif player_input == paper && computer_input == rock
    puts "Player chose paper. \nComputer chose rock"
    puts "Paper beats rock, player wins the round."
    $player_count += 1

  elsif computer_input == rock && player_input == scissors
    puts "Player chose scissors. \nComputer chose rock."
    puts "Rock beats scissos, Computer wins the round"
    $computer_count += 1

  elsif computer_input == scissors && player_input == paper
    puts "Player chose paper. \nComputer chose scissors."
    puts "Scissors beats paper, Computer wins the round"
    $computer_count += 1

  elsif computer_input == paper && player_input == rock
    puts "Player chose rock. \nComputer chose paper."
    puts "Paper beats rock, Computer wins the round"
    $computer_count += 1

  # elsif player_input == computer_input
  #   puts "Player chose #{player_input},\n Computer chose #{computer_input}"
  #   puts "Tie, choose again"  #tried with this but returns r, s, p instead of word

  elsif player_input == rock && computer_input == rock ||
        player_input == paper && computer_input == paper ||
        player_input == scissors && computer_input == scissors
    puts "Player chose rock. \nComputer chose rock."
    puts "Tie, choose again"
  end

  if player_input.include?("abcdefghijklmnoqtuvxzy")
    puts "Invalid entry, try again."
  end

  if $player_count == 2
    puts "Player wins!"
    break
  elsif $computer_count == 2
    puts "Computer wins!"
    break
  end
end
```

ok, I am new to this, and i understand there is a better way of writing a rock paper scissors with less typing and better methods. I'm just not there yet. so bear with me.

The code works but sometimes when i enter "r", "p", "s" it returns nothing, or "Invalid entry, try again." I have tried entering ranges

`if player_input = ["a".."o"].to_s` in case the player's input was anything else than the commands for the game. but still. I tried the include? method

can anyone tell me how to work only the r, p, s. and give "Invalid entry, try again" for everything else? in this code.

Answer (score 3):

### Loop with Conditional Break

One way to do this is with a loop that breaks only when you have valid input. For example:

```
loop do
  print "Choose rock (r), paper (p), or scissors (s): "
  player_input = gets.chomp.downcase
  break if player_input =~ /^[rps]$/
  puts "Invalid entry, try again."
end
```

There are certainly other ways to do this, and more idiomatic ways, too. However, this should address your specific question without too much refactoring.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what the =~ /^ $/ do. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Diego They anchor the regular expression to the start and end of the string. Without them, something like `foos` or `pbar` would also match, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: i see, I'm reading more about the regexp stuff. I tried working with that snipped in my code i wasn't successful. Do i switch my while loop for the loop do? to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

The =~ is testing for a regular expression in Ruby. Anything in between (2) slashes... `/^[rps]$/` is a regular expression.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html

^ Good information there on regular expressions.

Comment: Pattern matching may be achieved by using =~ operator or #match method. Got it

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more compact and Ruby-like way to write the game.

```
ENTRY_TO_SYM = { 'p'=>:PAPER, 'r'=>:ROCK, 's'=>:SCISSORS }
VALID_ENTRIES = ENTRY_TO_SYM.keys
COMPUTER_CHOICES = ENTRY_TO_SYM.values
# WINNERS and LOSERS from the player's perspective, the first value of each
# pair being the player's choice, the second, the computer's choice.
WINNERS = [[:SCISSORS, :PAPER], [:PAPER, :ROCK], [:ROCK, :SCISSORS]]
LOSERS =  WINNERS.map { |i,j| [j,i] }
```

.

```
class RockPaperScissors
  def initialize
    @player_score = @computer_score = @ties = 0
  end

  def play(winning_score)
    while @player_score < winning_score && @computer_score < winning_score
      puts "Player score: #{@player_score}, " +
           "Computer score: #{@computer_score}, Ties: #{@ties}"

      player = player_choice 
      computer = COMPUTER_CHOICES.sample
      puts "\nPlayer chooses #{player.to_s}"
      puts "Computer chooses #{computer.to_s}"

      case player_outcome [player, computer]
      when :WIN
        puts "#{player.to_s} beats #{computer.to_s}, player wins the round"
        @player_score += 1
      when :LOSE
        puts "#{computer.to_s} beats #{player.to_s}, computer wins the round"
        @computer_score += 1
      else
        puts "Tie, choose again"
        @ties += 1
      end
    end
    puts "\nFinal score: player: #{@player_score}, " +
         "computer: #{@computer_score} (ties: #{@ties})"
    puts (@player_score == 2) ? "Player wins!" : "Yea! Computer wins!"
  end
```

.

```
  private

  def player_choice
    loop do
      print "Choose rock (r), paper (p) or scissors (s): "
      choice = gets.chomp.downcase
      return ENTRY_TO_SYM[choice] if ENTRY_TO_SYM.key?(choice)
      puts "That entry is invalid. Please re-enter"
    end
  end

  def player_outcome(plays)
    return :WIN  if WINNERS.include?(plays)
    return :LOSE if LOSERS.include?(plays)
    :TIE
  end
end
```

.

```
RockPaperScissors.new.play(3)
```

A few things to note:

- I've relegated the getting of a valid entry from the player to a separate method, where I use [Kernel#loop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) (generally preferred to `while true`, etc.) for looping.
- I've used symbols to represent both choices and outcomes.
- I used the method [Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-sample) to obtain the computer's random choice.
- I've used arrays to represent winning and losing pairs of choices (from the player's perspective).

Comment: wow! yea i would need more time, knowledge and practice to accomplish it that way. Thanks for your input.

Comment: An anonymous person proposed a substantial edit. The edit contained some interesting ideas, and was well-constructed, but I prefer what I have and therefore did not accept the edit. I do, however, encourage that person to post a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Using too much `||` and if/elsif is really weird for this problem. You can do something much simpler like this:

```
# I inserted the logic here in this method, so we can always
# call the game
def rock_scissors_paper(user_choice)
    options = ["rock", "scissors", "paper"]

    computer_choice = options.sample
    computer_index = options.index(computer_choice)
    user_index = options.index(user_choice)


    puts "The computer went with #{computer_choice}"

    # Example:
    # If user chooses Rock (0 - 1) and computer paper (2), computer WINS 
    #   because options[-1] is... paper (whenever this is equal, computer wins)


    # If user chooses Paper (2 - 1) and computer rock (0), user WINS (ELSE)
    # And so on. 
    # Pay careful attention to how we checking against VALUES (-1 is the last guy!)
    if options[user_index - 1] == options[computer_index]
        puts "Computer wins the game!"
    elsif computer_choice == user_choice
        puts "It's a draw"
    else
        puts "You win the game"
    end
end



# Display options to the users
puts "Rock, scissors, paper?"
user_choice = gets.chomp.downcase


# Run method
rock_scissors_paper(user_choice)
```

Answer (score -1):

so i think the issue was that you needed to define the player like you did with the computer. i redid the assignment using the same things as you and it now seems to work. $player_count = 0
$computer_count = 0

```
def computer_input
  computer = rand(3)
  if computer == 0
    computer = "p"
  elsif computer == 1
    computer = "r"
  else
    computer = "s"
  end
end

    def player_input
  if player == "r"
    player = "r"
  elsif player == "p"
    player = "p"
  else player == "s"
    player = "s"
  end
end

while true

  puts "Player Score: #{$player_count}, \tComputer Score: #{$computer_count}"

  puts "Choose rock (r), paper (p), or scissors (s) "

  player_input = gets.chomp

  if player_input == "r" && computer_input == "s"
    puts "Player chose rock. \nComputer chose scissors."
    puts "Rock beats scissors, player wins the round."
    $player_count += 1

  elsif player_input == "s" && computer_input == "p"
    puts "Player chose scissors. \nComputer chose paper."
    puts "Scissors beat paper, player wins the round."
    $player_count += 1

  elsif player_input == "p" && computer_input == "r"
    puts "Player chose paper. \nComputer chose rock"
    puts "Paper beats rock, player wins the round."
    $player_count += 1

  elsif computer_input == "r" && player_input == "s"
    puts "Player chose scissors. \nComputer chose rock."
    puts "Rock beats scissos, Computer wins the round"
    $computer_count += 1

  elsif computer_input == "s" && player_input == "p"
    puts "Player chose paper. \nComputer chose scissors."
    puts "Scissors beats paper, Computer wins the round"
    $computer_count += 1

  elsif computer_input == "p" && player_input == "r"
    puts "Player chose rock. \nComputer chose paper."
    puts "Paper beats rock, Computer wins the round"
    $computer_count += 1

  elsif player_input == computer_input
    puts "Tie, go again!"

  else
    puts "Invalid Entry"
  end

  if $player_count == 2
    puts "Player wins!"
    break
  elsif $computer_count == 2
    puts "Computer wins!"
    break
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!!